# Type Error occurred when creating object on mass action with override

Tags: magento2.3.1

I've created a custom module to show order comments on the **invoice which works ok with single invoices**. When trying to print invoices via the order grid mass action I get this error:

```
{"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Sales\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Order\\Pdfinvoices\\Interceptor","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create('Magento\\Sales\\Co...', array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Sales\\Co...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/ActionFactory.php:44]
#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Sales\\Co...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:304]
#4 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->matchAction(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#, array('areaFrontName' => 'adminarea', 'moduleFrontName' => 'sales', 'actionPath' => 'order', 'actionName' => 'pdfinvoices', 'variables' => array('key' => 'a16160358ca3a448...'))) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:165]
#5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->match(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:95]
#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]
#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]
#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000004aa3a963000000000d13c128#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]
#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:258]
#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000004aa3a99c000000000d13c128#) called at [index.php:39]
<\/pre>","url":"\/adminarea\/sales\/order\/pdfinvoices\/key\/a16160358ca3a44836acecccac1531300de1f39f164af578cad46aa2f98aa8d6\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Here's my module code:
**app\code\Denial\InvoiceComments\registration.php**

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Denial_InvoiceComments', __DIR__);
```

**app\code\Denial\InvoiceComments\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

**app\code\Denial\InvoiceComments\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Denial_InvoiceComments" setup_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Sales" />
   </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

**app\code\Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;


class Invoice extends AbstractPdf
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
 */
protected $_localeResolver;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param Config $pdfConfig
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    Config $pdfConfig,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
    parent::__construct(
        $paymentData,
        $string,
        $scopeConfig,
        $filesystem,
        $pdfConfig,
        $pdfTotalFactory,
        $pdfItemsFactory,
        $localeDate,
        $inlineTranslation,
        $addressRenderer,
        $data
    );
}


/**
 * Draw header for item table
 *
 * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
 * @return void
 */
protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
{
    /* Add table head */
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
    $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
    $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
    $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
    $this->y -= 10;
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

    //columns headers
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 375, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

    $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $this->y -= 20;
}

/**
 * Return PDF document
 *
 * @param array|Collection $invoices
 * @return \Zend_Pdf
 */
public function getPdf($invoices = [])
{
   $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }

        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add address */
        $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add head */
        $this->insertOrder(
            $page,
            $order,
            $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $order->getStoreId()
            )
        );
        /* Add document text and number */
        $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
        /* Add table */
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
        /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
        /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }

    foreach ($invoice->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
    $textChunk = wordwrap(strip_tags($status->getComment()), 120, "\n");
    foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
            if ($textLine!=='') {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
            }
    }
    }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}


/**
 * Create new page and assign to PDF object
 *
 * @param  array $settings
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
 */
public function newPage(array $settings = [])
{
    /* Add new table head */
    $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
    $this->y = 800;
    if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
    }
    return $page;
}

}
```

**app\code\Denial\InvoiceComments\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_invoice_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_comments">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Denial_InvoiceComments::order/comments/view.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**app\code\Denial\InvoiceComments\view\adminhtml\templates\order\comments\view.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($_entity = $block->getEntity()): ?>
<div id="comments_block" class="edit-order-comments">
    <div class="order-history-block">
        <div class="admin__field field-row">
            <label class="admin__field-label"
                for="history_comment"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Comment Text') ?></label>
            <div class="admin__field-control">
                <textarea name="comment[comment]"
                        class="admin__control-textarea"
                        rows="3"
                        cols="5"
                        id="history_comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__field">
            <div class="order-history-comments-options">
                <?php if ($block->canSendCommentEmail()): ?>
                    <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                        <input name="comment[is_customer_notified]"
                            type="checkbox"
                            class="admin__control-checkbox"
                            id="history_notify"
                            value="1" />
                        <label class="admin__field-label"
                            for="history_notify"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Notify Customer by Email') ?></label>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                    <input name="comment[is_visible_on_front]"
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="history_visible"
                        class="admin__control-checkbox"
                        value="1" />
                    <label class="admin__field-label"
                        for="history_visible"> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Visible on Storefront') ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="order-history-comments-actions">
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('submit_button') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<h3> Order Comments </h3>
<ul class="note-list">
<?php foreach ($_entity->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status): ?>
    <?php  if ($status->getComment()): ?>
    <span class="note-list-date"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($status->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
            <span class="note-list-time"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatTime($status->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
            <span class="note-list-customer">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer') ?>
                <?php if ($status->getIsCustomerNotified()): ?>
                    <span class="note-list-customer-notified"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Notified') ?></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="note-list-customer-not-notified"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Not Notified') ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
    <div class="note-list-comment"><?= $block->escapeHtml($status->getComment(), ['b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<h3> Invoice Comments </h3>    
<ul class="note-list">
        <?php foreach ($_entity->getCommentsCollection(true) as $_comment): ?>
            <li>
                <span class="note-list-date"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($_comment->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
                <span class="note-list-time"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatTime($_comment->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
                <span class="note-list-customer">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer') ?>
                    <?php if ($_comment->getIsCustomerNotified()): ?>
                        <span class="note-list-customer-notified"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Notified') ?></span>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <span class="note-list-customer-not-notified"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Not Notified') ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
                <div class="note-list-comment"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_comment->getComment(), ['b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a']) ?></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
require(['prototype'], function(){

submitComment = function() {
    submitAndReloadArea($('comments_block').parentNode, '<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSubmitUrl() ?>')
}

if ($('submit_comment_button')) {
    $('submit_comment_button').observe('click', submitComment);
}

});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What have I missed?

More info from the logs:

```
[2019-12-05 09:58:31] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfinvoices\Interceptor, Argument 6 passed to Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfinvoices\Interceptor::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice, instance of Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice given, called in /home/sitename/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 [] []
[2019-12-05 09:58:31] main.ERROR: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfinvoices\Interceptor [] []
```

How do I change the required instance name?

Answer (score 2):

Please replace following code in

> Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php file

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf;

    use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice as MagentoInvoice;

    class Invoice extends MagentoInvoice
    {

        /**
         * Draw header for item table
         *
         * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
         * @return void
         */
        protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {
            /* Add table head */
            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

            //columns headers
            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 375, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

            $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $this->y -= 20;
        }

        /**
         * Return PDF document
         *
         * @param array|Collection $invoices
         * @return \Zend_Pdf
         */
        public function getPdf($invoices = [])
        {
            $this->_beforeGetPdf();
            $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

            $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
            $this->_setPdf($pdf);
            $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
            $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

            foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
                if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                    $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
                }

                $page = $this->newPage();
                $order = $invoice->getOrder();
                /* Add image */
                $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
                /* Add address */
                $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
                /* Add head */
                $this->insertOrder(
                    $page,
                    $order,
                    $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                        self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        $order->getStoreId()
                    )
                );
                /* Add document text and number */
                $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
                /* Add table */
                $this->_drawHeader($page);
                /* Add body */
                foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* Draw item */
                    $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                    $page = end($pdf->pages);
                }
                /* Add totals */
                $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
                if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                    $this->_localeResolver->revert();
                }

                foreach ($invoice->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
                    $textChunk = wordwrap(strip_tags($status->getComment()), 120, "\n");
                    foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
                        if ($textLine!=='') {
                            $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                            $this->y -= 15;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->_afterGetPdf();
            return $pdf;
        }


        /**
         * Create new page and assign to PDF object
         *
         * @param  array $settings
         * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
         */
        public function newPage(array $settings = [])
        {
            /* Add new table head */
            $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
            $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
            $this->y = 800;
            if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
                $this->_drawHeader($page);
            }
            return $page;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem,
As per log sixth argument of `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfinvoices` must be type of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice`. You have defined preference for `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice`. So, magetno will use `Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice` instead of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice`.

And here is the solution,
 Extend `Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice` to `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice` and override necessary code.

```
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    \\ Your code here
}
```